# JavaFX: Is there a simple way to change the method of the onAction Handler in the code?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a Login Button who looks like this:

```
<Button fx:id="loginButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doLogin" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="127.46630859375" text="Login" />
```

When the button is clicked I want to set the onAction to `"#doLogout"`in the code

I know there is a button.setOnAction method, but it has ActionEvent parameter and I have the problem that in the inner class, which I would have to make when I use this option, I do not have access to the variables in the outher class, which I need.

Is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: Pass a reference of the outer class to the inner class. Don't create a static inner class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
//In the Controller class
@FXML
private Button loginButton = new Button();
//... 
//... on The  public void initialize method of the Controller
//...
loginButton.setId("loginButton");
loginButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                            Object source = e.getSource();
                            if (source instanceof Button) { //always true
                               //Do whatever you want when the event occurs 
                               Button temp = (Button) source;
                                DoSomething(temp.getId());
                            }
                        }
});
```

**Then after the login:**

loginButton.setId("logoutButton");

**or create a flag:**

```
public boolean userLogged = false;
```

and check it to define what the button should do as here:

```
loginButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                            if(userLogged) 
                              doLogout();
                            else
                              doLogin();

                        }
});
```